# electron-packager win32 don't open window

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I have tried to build a very simple app with Electron, Node and AngularJS. The app is working well till I pack it. After packing, it doesn't show the window.

The ideea was to run a NodeJS process on localhost:5000, then to load the url in ElectronJS main window. When I double-click on .exe file, the process is starting at localhost:5000 and it's working in the browser only, but the Electron window is not shown.

Also, It crash when trying to open with `npm run start` / `npm start`

> "Windows Script Host. Error: Syntax error. Code: 800A03EA. Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error."

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  }
```

**server.js**

```
'use strict';
const
express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.set('port', (5000));
app.use(express.static('app'));
app.use(express.static('dist'));
app.use(express.static('node_modules'));

app.get("*", (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/app/index.html");
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Node server is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'));
});
```

**electron.js**

```
'use strict';
const 
electron = require('electron'),
server = require('./server.js'),
{app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

app.on('ready', () => {
    var win = new BrowserWindow({
        show: false,
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    });

    win.loadURL("http://localhost:5000/");

    win.on('ready-to-show', function() {
        win.show();
        win.focus();
    });

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    });
});
```

> I can find the process in task manager.
>
> NodeJS is running on localhost:5000. I can see it in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that is a versioning incompatibility. At least, in my case was.

The following combination fixed my problem:

> `"electron": "^3.0.4"` with `"electron-packager": "^12.2.0"`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any issues with your code. But I did find a related issue which might be impacting you: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7779

Can you start electron in debug mode and check if the ready-to-show event fired?

Comment: I'm new with ElectronJS and I don't know how to start in debug mode. I have switched the `show: false` to `show: true` and I have removed the `ready-to-show` event. But it's the same effect.

Comment: Instead of running electron using `npm run start`, use `electron inspect-brk .`. Once you've done that, open Google Chrome browser and goto `chrome://inspect`. There you should see an item under the 'Remote Target' section. Click on that and a new debugger window will open up. You can use this to debug your code line by line similar to how you debug your frontend code in the browser.

Comment: `electron inspect-brk .` returns an error "Error lunching app. Cannot find module inspect-brk".

Comment: Ok, the correct command was `electron --inspect .` The server is starting at port 5000 and the Electron window is displayed. Let me pack it again, I'll be back to you with an answer.

Comment: I have packed it and the same result. It's working only in the browser, the Electron window is not appearing. However, how can I know what command is triggered when clicking on the .exe file ? I can use the --inspector flag only manual in dev mode, before packing.

Comment: How exactly are you 'packing' the app? Are you using electron-builder?